# Why is UIViewPropertyAnimator not initialising?

Tags: ios, animation

When I try to initialise `UIViewPropertyAnimator` in response to user pan gesture I get `nil`.
The view I try to animate is just a simple `UIView` created in Interface Builder:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *overlayView;
```

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)onControlPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        int newTop = _overlayView.frame.origin.y + 50;

        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(_overlayView.frame.origin.x, newTop,
            _overlayView.frame.size.width, _overlayView.frame.size.height);

        animator = [[UIViewPropertyAnimator alloc] initWithDuration:1
            curve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
            animations:^{
              _overlayView.frame = newFrame;
        }];
        [animator startAnimation]; // here animator is nil
    }
}
```

Can object initialisation be somehow disabled? By third party library or framework maybe?

Strange thing is that when I animate same view without animator init using below code the animation works as expected:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    _overlayView.frame = newFrame;
}];
```

But this is not solutions for me, because I need animator object to cancel animation at some point.

Comment: code seems legit. are your sure animator = nil ? when do you try to start the animation?

Comment: @giorashc - Debugger shows me animator = nil, I don't know how to be more sure. I try to start animation right after animator initialisation (but it doesn't start since animator is nil). If you wanted to ask when I try to init animator - I do it in reaction to user pan gesture, after gesture is finished (state = `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`).

Comment: Ok, can you show that part of code?

Comment: @giorashc - I edited my question to show part of code you asked for

Comment: How is the `animator` property defined?

Comment: @David - `@interface MyViewController () { UIViewPropertyAnimator* animator; }`, does it matter for initialisation?

Comment: @MarekJ. I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't `weak` and disappeared before it was used.